# Import into Mysql Via .CSV File

Tags: mysql, csv, load-data-infile

Currently have : `LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '/Users/RkG/Desktop/Microblogs.csv' INTO TABLE blogs`

[image: import]

This is an example of the data im trying to import.
[image: img2]

[image: img3]

The last image is a result of the query I ran and the second image is a screenshot of the table structure, why isn't it importing the 'created on', 'location', and 'Text' ???

By trying the method given below I'm giving this output: How do I fix this date format??
[image: img]

**PLAINTEXT:**

```
3,5/18/2011 13:26,42.22717 93.33772,this convention filled with technology could be better don't plan on leaving anytime soon
3,5/10/2011 9:22,42.18881 93.35642,4 orang top scorer skrg  3 di antara nya pake adidas F50 adizero  Lightest fastest deadliest.
3,5/14/2011 9:22,42.22479 93.35922,Nike 'gana' el Mundial al patrocinador oficial Adidas // y eso que sus figuras fueron un fracaso rotundo...
3,5/6/2011 9:22,42.2469 93.32527,Positiiff    mau nabung beli kaos adidas aslii muller .. * basii bgt baru nabung skrg ya  hahaha
```

Comment: 5/7/11 2:50 seems to be a datetime. Do you want to load only date part? Moreover you have to use set syntax within load data to turn this string in the right format.

Comment: Can you show a code example please?

Comment: I'll try to post the code when you'll answer to my previous question :) Moreover it would be useful if you post 3 or 4 lines of your csv as plain text instead of images. In this way we can try more quickly the code.

Comment: @Nick - thanks for the reply with code. Ill have to put plain text for following posts. Thanks again

Comment: Nick please see the problem above i now run into with the below code

Comment: In your image created_at is a datetime field, not a date one. We need to know the order of modifiers. Update your question with some datetime rows of your csv (in plain text please) that you have and specify in which order they are (day,month and so on).

Comment: See plain text above, and its in order of M:DD:YYYY

Comment: @user700070, please stop editing the question and coming up with different info every time, it is very confusing!!!! Just put the info in there in one, maybe 2 go's, please.

Comment: Sorry about that Johan - Nick helped me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Supposing that you change created_at from date to datetime this would give you an idea.
Adapt date modifiers to your needs (i don't know date and month order in your string).

```
load data local infile '/Users/RkG/Desktop/Microblogs.csv'
into table blogs 
fields terminated by ','
lines terminated by '\n'
(id,@created_at,location,text)
set created_at = str_to_date(@created_at,'%c/%d/%Y %k:%i')
```

If that last line does not work for you see:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date

Comment: This works for everything, exept the date field, it is making all the date fields blank.... any reason why

Comment: You need to change to last line to something like `set created_at = str_to_date(@created_at,'%y-%m-%d %h:%i')`. Probably some experimentation will be needed to get it right.

Comment: @user700070: I had already asked you to post some row in plain text. What do you want to store? Only date and remove time part or what? Please be more specifi in order to have a right answer.

Comment: @Johan - this doesnt seem to work.. still gives 0000-00-0000 00 00 for the 'created_at' column

Comment: try this one set created_at = str_to_date(@created_at,'%c/%d/%Y %k:%i')

Comment: You da man nick! Now if you could just explain why this works and why the other doesn't :) ????

Comment: Because str_to_date() requires that you pass to it the right modifiers in the right order. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format As you can see %c stand for month without leading zero, %Y stands for year with 4 digits and so on. :) If you've solved I update my answer.

Comment: You're welcome. Thanks to Johan for his kind support and his patience. Sometimes it's really hard ;)

Answer (score 0):

better try this application for importing .**CSV** or .**XLS** file directly into mysql database http://bloggerplugnplay.blogspot.in/2013/01/tool-to-import-csv-and-xls-to-mysql.html